# SharePoint 2010: how to programatically retrieve connection string to Social DB

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

That's it - any way to programatically retrieve connection string to Social DB?

Tried instantiating the private SocialDatabase class but got nowhere because sdb.ConnectionString looked null (the entire object looked dehydrated, and couldn't figure out how to fill it in).

```
Assembly up = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll");
object sdb = up.CreateInstance("Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SocialDatabase", true,
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.CreateInstance,
                    null, null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, null);
```

Ideas appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be totally doable.  One way of attacking this problem is starting with the SPFarm object and getting the collection of services.

```
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
SPServiceCollection services = farm.Services;
```

That will contain the collection of SPService objects for you farm.  There will be a ton of them in a farm that is running a lot of services.  Printing out the .Name and .TypeName of each SPService object will quickly give you a scheme for finding the right SPService instance.

Then it is a matter of cruising around the API of the specific class that implements the social data in order to find the right property that will return an SPDatabase object that you want.